# MySQL Left Join Taking awhile

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a list of possible customers along with the sum of their order history (ltv)

Without the order by, this query loads in under a second.  With the `order by` and the query is taking over 90 seconds.

```
SELECT a.customerid,a.firstname,a.lastname,Orders.ltv  
    FROM customers a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT customerid,
               SUM(amount) as ltv 
        FROM orders 
       GROUP BY customerid) Orders 
     ON Orders.customerid=a.customerid  
ORDER BY 
   Orders.ltv DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Any ideas how this could be sped up?

EDIT: I guess I cleaned up the query a little too much.  The query is acually a little more complicated then this version.  Other data is selected from the customers table, and can be sorted against as well.

Comment: My guess is that you are running a query against tables without proper indexes.  My guess is that you also don't need the subselect.  Can you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE customers` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE orders` and place the results in your question? Actually in looking at your query, I don;t see why you join customers table at all sine you are only getting customerid from it (this same value already exists in orders table.

Comment: @user2864740: which it would, coming from a subquery, no indexes on that ;)

Comment: @jwatkins You don't need to do a subselect there at all. You can calculate sum without need for subselect.

Comment: @MikeBrant I need the subselect, I've only put in piece of the query.  I need the query to function as a `left join`.

Comment: As far as indexes... on customers, the primary key is customerid, and there is a index on orders.customerid

Comment: @MikeBrant Forget my comment. Just checked MySQL doc, and ordering by a projection field is indeed allowed. Sorry for the noise ;)

Comment: @Michael What do you mean by you have only put in a piece of the query?  If you want suggestions on a poorly performing query, you should include the full query.

Comment: @MikeBrant Well the question was asked about a LEFT JOIN, not anything else.

Comment: @Michael Understood, but if you are only looking for 10 rows of data, and it sounds like you have a considerable amount of data based on the query times you mentioned, then the suggestion to remove customerid's without any amounts from the query is one you might consider, as it will alleviate the need to include those rows in unindexed sort.  The reality of the situation is that if your app requires this sort of data with a quick query response on a regular basis (i.e. this is not for occasional admin report) then you might consider storing a table with order totals, with index on those totals

Comment: @MikeBrant I have thought about the possibility of storing the totals  -- Just trying to avoid it if I can :)

Comment: @Michael See my edited answer based on your updated post showing the need for additional fields on customers table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the actual schema it is a bit hard to know how data is related but I guess this query should be equivalent and more performant:

```
SELECT a.customerid, coalesce(sum(o.amount), 0) TotalLtv FROM customers a
LEFT JOIN orders o ON a.customerid = o.cusomterid
GROUP BY a.customerid
ORDER BY TotalLtv DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The `coalesce` will make sure you return `0` for the customers without orders.

As @ypercube made me notice, an index on `amount` won't help either. You could give it a try to:

```
ALTER TABLE orders ADD INDEX(customer, amount)
```

**After your question update**

If you need to add more fields that functionally depend on the `a.customerid` in the select clause you can use the non-standard MySQL `group by` clause. This will result in better performance than grouping by `a.customerid, a.firstname, a.lastname`:

```
SELECT a.customerid, a.firstname, a.lastname, coalesce(sum(o.amount), 0) TotalLtv
FROM customers a
LEFT JOIN orders o ON a.customerid = o.cusomterid
GROUP BY a.customerid
ORDER BY TotalLtv DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: The index on `(amount)` will not help at all. An index on `(customerid, amount)` might.

Comment: Whoops, you're clearly right. And the one you propose is even not going to help much at all either but it worths trying.

Comment: This is a huge improvement even without the index.  Thanks!

Comment: @Michael Welcome. I updated the answer and added just a simple detail about the `group by` that might be useful.

Comment: @Michael ((3200 log 3200) * 0.008) ~90 seconds   formula to show you why it takes 90 seconds based on quicksort best case and linear random acces time of a 7.2K disk  this could happen when explain shows "Using temporary; using filesort"; if your memory is full MySQL need to create an MyISAM disk based temporary table thats quicksorted with disk I/O in this case an resultset off 3200 records

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes. I'd recommend you to read the MySQL docs as it is explained in there when to use them and when not to. Once you have, check my answer again and see that I've clearly stated `If you need to add more fields that functionally depend on the a.customerid`. If you still have doubts about it, please, create a chat session and I'll be happy to keep discussing this with you (questions with more than 5 comments get flagged and require privileged users to unflag them). Thanks.

Comment: @Mosty Mostacho +1  and excuse me i totally read over the text above the query to much focus on the query..

Answer (score 2):

A few things here.  First it doesn't appear that you need to join the `customers` table at all here since you are only using it for the `customerid`, which already exists in `orders` table.  If you have more than 10 customer id's with corresponding amounts, you will never even need to see the list of customer id's which don;t have amounts that you would get with LEFT JOIN from customers. As such, you should be able to reduce your query to this:

```
SELECT customerid, SUM(amount) AS ltv
FROM orders
GROUP BY customerid
ORDER BY ltv DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

You would need an index on customerid. Unfortunately, the sort is on a calculated field, so there is not a lot you can do to speed this up from that point.

I see the updated question.  Since you do need additional fields from customers, I will revise my answer to include the customer table

```
SELECT c.customerid, c.firstname, c.lastname, coalesce(o.ltv, 0) AS total
FROM customers AS c
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT customerid, SUM(amount) as ltv
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY customerid
    ORDER BY ltv DESC LIMIT 0,10) AS o
ON c.customerid = o.customerid
```

Note that I am joining on a sub-selected table as you were doing in your original query, however I have performed the sort and limit on the sub-selected table so you don't have to sort all the records without any entries on orders table.

Comment: Assuming, customers with a Order-Sum of "0" can be left out of the result.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. First, don't use an inner query. MySQL does allow ORDER BY on a projection alias. Second, you should get a considerable improvment by having a B-TREE index on the composed key (customerid, amount). Then the engine will be able to execute this query by a simple traversal of the index, without fetching any row data.